# Utilizando foreign key com cascade

Tags: php, mysql, chave-estrangeira

Em meu sistema, ao apagar uma publicação, todos os comentários que possuem o `id_publicacao` igual ao da publicação são deletados de uma tabela chamada `comentarios_publicacao`. E eu faço isso simplesmente fazendo uma verificação do tipo:

```
if(deletar a publicacao) {
    então eu apago todos os comentários com a id_publicacao igual ao da publicacao que foi apagada
}
```

Então eu estava fazendo umas pesquisas do Google quando me deparei com a famosa `Foreign Key` então fui pesquisar sobre. Porém não entendi muito bem... Vi também algo relacionado a `Cascade` que no caso se eu apagasse algo na "tabela pai", tudo relacionado a ela em "tabelas filhas" também seriam apagadas. Eu poderia substituir o método que utilizo (assim como o "exemplo" que dei acima) por esse das tabelas filhas etc? E como faria isso? Como esse assunto é novo para mim ainda estou meio perdido, vi várias explicações em blogs e sites sobre `Foreign Key` porém não consegui entender realmente quando utiliza-la. Alguém poderia me dar uma explicação clara e direta sobre o conceito de `Chave Estrangeira` e seus derivados (tipo, o que são constraints, cascade, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É através da utilização de *Chaves estrageiras(Foreign Key)* que as Bases de Dados Relacionais garantem a *Integridade referencial(Referential integrity)*.

As chaves estrangeiras servem para definir relações entre tabelas.
A relação é definida pela inclusão de um ou mais campos na tabela *filha* que representam a chave primária da tabela *pai*.  A esses campos dá-se o nome de *chave estrangeira*.

Esta relação faz-se criado uma *FOREIGN KEY Constraint*(restrição por chave estrangeira).
Chama-se restrição(constraint) porque, após a relação entre as tabelas ter sido definida, as operações sobre as duas tabelas ficam condicionadas de forma a garantir a integridade dos dados.

Essa garantia passa por não permitir:

1 - incluir na tabela *filha* valores que não existam na tabela *pai*.
2 - excluir registos da tabela *pai* que estejam referenciados na tabela *filha*.

Para facilitar a eliminação de registos da tabela *pai* sem violar a segunda restrição, a *FOREIGN KEY Constraint* pode ser criada com a opção *DELETE CASCADE*.
Esta opção informa a base de dados para que, quando um registo *pai* for eliminado, elimine todos os registos da tabela *filha* que tenham referência a ele.

A *FOREIGN KEY Constraint* pode ser criada no `CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE comentarios_publicacao
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    .......,
    .......,
    Id_publicacao int,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Id_publicacao) REFERENCES Publicacao(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

ou no `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE comentarios_publicacao
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Id_publicacao)
REFERENCES Publicacao(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, consegui finalmente entender alguma coisa hehe. Apenas uma dúvida: No exemplo que você deu utilizando o `CASCADE` ele só vai deletar o que tiver o `comentarios_publicacao(id_publicacao)` igual ao do `publicacao(id)` correto?

Comment: Exatamente. Elimina os "filhos" cuja chave estrangeira é igual à chave primária do "pai" eliminado.